# MVC handle exception from a child async method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, async-await

How to handle an exception from the thread of a child action in MVC?

In this example an exception from the MakePayment method is not handled by the catch of the calling action:

Action in controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Payment()
{

    try
    {
        var tokenId = "12345";
        var order = new OrderViewModel
                    {
                        Amount = 10.00,
                        Description = "Widget",
                        Customer = 1                         
                     };

        var payment = new PaymentService();
        var model = await payment.MakeCharge(tokenId, order);

    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = ex.Message.toString();
        return view("Failed");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Payment class:

```
public class PaymentService
{
  public async Task<Charge> MakeCharge(string tokenId, OrderViewModel order)
  {
     return await Task.Run(() =>
     {
       var myCharge = new ChargeCreateOptions
       { 
          Amount = order.Amount,
          Description = order.Description,
          TokenId = tokenId
       };

       var chargeService = new ChargeService();
       var charge = chargeService.create(mycharge);    

       return charge;       

     });
  }
}
```

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: What makes you think an exception is being thrown and not handled?

Comment: By using ‘Task.Run‘ in an ASP.NET application you are paying the costs of complexity and thread switching without any benefits.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I for the time being there is no support for this as stated in the comments.

Apart from that boring answer I suggest that you read this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/magazine/dn683793(en-us).aspx about the news in try/catch async methods coming in c#6.

Now I don't see any reason to use `Task.Run()` in your example. An obvious example for when you should use `Task.Run()` is when you don't want to block you UI-thread when doing CPU-heavy work that's synchronous. In your case you don't have any UI-thread.